# bootstrap d-flex layout in mobile not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have three divs nested inside a parent div that look something like this:

```css
.button-class {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 45rem;
}

.svg-class {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex mb-3">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="button-class p-2">
    <ion-button></ion-button>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-class p-2">
    <svg></svg> //code
  </div>
</div>
```

where I have used `mr-auto` to align the first element to the extreme left, and the other two elements are supposed to go towards the left (but not extreme left) with a certain margin difference.

So, currently what my problem is that I want to show this in the following way. There is a text to the left, and a button and an info symbol svg to the right. And for mobile I want to the text and the button + svg group to go into a columnar style so to speak. So the button extends a bit until it takes almost 80% of the space of the column with the info symbol at the end.

[image]

For larger screens it appears fine, but when I do mobile settings, like either using a mobile version of `d-flex` or adding a line break after the text and before the button (which is visible only in mobile), it ceases to function, and appears as three elements side by side in mobile. For example, I changed `d-flex` to `d-md-flex` and got the button and the info-symbol inside a single div (to make them move into separate columns as a group), but then what happens is that in both mobile and larger screens the text and the button appear in one col, and the info-symbol moves to the next. Could anyone please help with this even if its with default CSS? I have tried a variety of different bootstrap classes and they do not work. Really struggling to figure out how best to do this in a way that fits both for larger screens and for smaller ones.

EDIT:

I have tried changing this to default CSS flex where I make the parent container a `flex-box` and then for the two child elements (one containing the text and the other the button and the svg) I give them `flex-grow` of 2 and 1 respectively, and then do a `flex-direction: row` in larger screens and `flex-direction: col` in smaller screens. It does work, but for some reason one problem with that is that I am unable to style the SVG element on its own, for example if I want to push it down by giving it a `margin-top`, it has sort of become an `svg` styling problem now.

Comment: Could you perhaps put those 3 divs each inside a col then using `col-sm-*` and `col-md-*` they will always be side by side?... Or maybe add the col class to the existing classes in those divs?

Comment: @CuteCodeRob I have tried doing something similar but with flex-box (added it in the original post). I think `col-sm-*` and `col-md-*` will work in the same way, and will probably give me the same issue as I have now, which is that svg styling doesn't work.

Comment: @QPTR I noticed you edited your question recently... did my solution not do what you want??

Comment: @カメロン I added a comment in the answer :) I used a different solution with parent as a flex container and child element with flex-grow attributes, it works but yours is neater, and I really do need a solution with bootstrap. The only thing is that the fact that I have an ion-button and an svg it becomes a little problemmatical to style them together (that is to get the final look of the button occupying about 90% of the width and the svg the remaining)

Comment: okay it just worked for me with a few margin adjustments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I basically just made what you had sketched up. I exchanged some markup for demonstration purposes, but these classes will work for you.

Essentially, Bootstrap doesn't have `xs` classes specifications in this version of Bootstrap. However, you can use `flex-sm-row` and `flex-column` classes for responsiveness. You could use `flex-sm-row` to keep the row horizontal on `sm` and up, then `flex-column` to stack vertically on xs screen widths (<576px).

I also added `text-center` or `text-align: center;` on your `h2` so that it is centered on a mobile device. I also changed your markup a bit. Re-size the browser below 576 pixels to see the mobile view. See the CSS and HTML changes below:

```css
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-between">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="text-center">text</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex mr-2 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="button-class">
      <button class="mr-3">Button</button>
    </div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/%3Fuestionmark_encircled.svg/1280px-%3Fuestionmark_encircled.svg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I really do appreciate the solution!! can I ask why did you use `justify-content-between` in the first div? my understanding is that it will place the wrapper and the second `d-flex` div at the start and middle positions respectively. But for some reason visually its positioning at start and end. Also one thing, how do we know that `flex-column` is for `xs` devices? your solution works, but if I have an `svg` instead of an `img` then the positioning gets a little problemmatical. I'll accept the answer tho since it does solve the basic problem!

Comment: `flex-column` is not for xs devices. It's because I have `sm-row` defined which just means `min-width 576px`. Therefore, everything above 576px will be a row. Then the `flex-column` will only kick in under 576px since it doesn't have any predefined size like sm, md, or lg. Hope that clears it up for you and may help you in how Bootstrap sizing works.  Glad you were able to figure it out as I read in the comments above. Once you have read this comment I will delete the others.

Comment: thank you so much! I think I got it! can you also explani why you used `justify-content-between` specifically?

Comment: It's the same as `justify-content: space-between`. It's simply a method of spacing out the two divs (`wrapper` and the second flex div containing image and button). You could use `space-around` or `space-evenly` if you didn't want them completely on the edge of the viewport. In short, `space-between` is my alternative to adding `margin-left: auto;` to the second div containing the button and image.

Answer (score -1):

Add this inside head tag.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
</head>
```

This will work for mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am working on angular with typescript, not working with jquery so this will not work.

Comment: ok. i'm not familiar with angular.  This link may be help you     https://nodejs.org/en/download/